# C# Xamarin : How to change navigation bar color?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I just simply want to change the bottom navigation bar's color to match my app's theme.

In which file, where and how can I change it?

For example [here](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-kFZTmeOAtNk%2FWNsY0GHJvrI%2FAAAAAAAAGLI%2F5t6STwHASgohc71wvsK9jnds4Yzm0nMJQCLcB%2Fs1600%2FAndroid-8-UI-Tuner-Navigation-Bar.jpg&f=1&nofb=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Android folder, in MainActivity.cs on method OnCreate, after the
`LoadApplication(new App());`
define your color like this:

```
var mainColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(29, 53, 87);
```

then set it:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
{
   Window.SetNavigationBarColor(mainColor);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for the navigation bar background. 
Is there any way to change the "foreground" color? (I mean the square, triangle etc.)

Comment: @FHJTDSDG I don't think you can do that, from what I know Android handles the foreground colors automatically.